# error: ‘Error’ is not a member of ‘cl’ - but it is

Tags: c++, exception, opencl

I'm trying to use the C++ bindings for OpenCL. This seems to be working; but when I try throwing an OpenCL-associated exception (myself), the code won't compile:

```
/path/to/src.cpp: error: ‘Error’ is not a member of ‘cl’
        throw cl::Error(result);
```

but I know there *is* a `cl::Error` class in the `cl.hpp` header. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

In order for the OpenCL C++ bindings to also define (and use?) exceptions, you have to have:

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
```

before including `cl.hpp`. Otherwise `cl::Error` is `#ifdef`'ed out of existence.